# Find number of instruments plm package R

Tags: r, instruments, plm

I am using the plm package for the GMM.
How can I see what is the **number of instruments used?**

Here is my code:

```
z1.ABquad <- pgmm(cpi ~ lag(cpi, 1:1)+lag(gdppc, 4:4) + lag(expense, 7:7) + lag(freedom, 0:0) + lag(freedom2, 3:3) | lag(cpi, 3:3) +  lag(democracy, 9:10) + lag(stability, 3:8) + lag(expense, 3:6) + lag(gdppc, 0:3) + lag(freedom, 3:4) + lag(freedom2, 2:7),
                  data = model,
                  effect = "twoways",
                  model = "twosteps",
                  collapse = FALSE,
                  time.dummies = TRUE,
                  subset = sample == 1)
mtest(z1.ABquad, order = 1L)
mtest(z1.ABquad, order = 2L, vcov = vcovHC)
summary(z1.ABquad, robust = FALSE)
sargan(z1.ABquad)
```

I tried to put: `inst.method = c("bvk", "baltagi", "am", "bms")`, but nothing changes.

Comment: Note that `inst.method` is not a valid argument for `pgmm`. Also note that - if it was one - it would only accept one of the values you mentioned.

Comment: Go for another package like `fixest`.